# ASP.NET strange behaviour: Adding Debug=true in web.config changes css

Tags: css, asp.net, debugging, web-config

Just as the question states: When I add debug=true to my web.config (no other changes anywhere in the code) my page is rendered with no background colour.

Any explanation why this should occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that there is some code that is checking if compilation is in debug mode and makes web page run different.

Why to use it, for example for enabling some debuging details.

Try to search for something like `IsDebuggingEnabled` in project